# Recursive function - printing out from zero up to passed number

Tags: recursion

I was given a problem to create a recursive function that prints out even numbers from 0 to the passed number. My problem? It can only have one parameter: `int counting(int n)`. I can't figure out how to do this. There are no loops in the main. You have to start at 0, but somehow get it to the value you're passing.

Any ideas on the method?

Answer (score 1):

With recursion, you want to think of the base case (the case at which the recursion will stop and you'll start returning up the call stack). In this case, your method needs to keep calling itself until it gets down to 0. This implies that you'd need to keep calling it after reducing the parameter by 1 until the value reaches 0. Then you'd need to check whether the number is even or not and, if so, print the number.

Here's an example:

```
def printeven(n):
   if n > 0: 
     printeven(n-1)
   if n % 2 ==0:
     print n
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the recursive call before the printing - it will do the trick.
In Java:

```
int counting(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return n;
    int res = counting(n - 1);
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(n);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The codes everyone gave is the same including this one in `c`.

```
int counting(int n) {
    if(n)
        counting(n-1);
    if(!(n%2))
        printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

The trick is to keep recursing until the parameter reaches `0`, then start printing the number before returning to the caller.